# Delete item from database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to delete an item onLongClick of listview,
but the selected item is not being deleted. Here's my database delete method:

```
  public int deleteReminderEntry(Model id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    return db.delete(REMINDER_TABLE_NAME, REMINDER_COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {Integer.toString(id.getId())});
}
```

and my delete action:

```
model.getId();
database.deleteReminderEntry(model);
reminderListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Its deleted, i think you have notifyDataSetChanged but dont seems to remove item from list of `model` . Also check what `deleteReminderEntry()` method returns

Comment: Why are you not using a CursorAdapter in your listview?

Answer (score 0):

You changed the data in the database, not data in the adapter.

After deleting from the database, either fetch the data again and recreate the adapter or delete the item from the `ArrayList` passed to the adapter.

Comment: Or use a CursorAdapter so that a database copy in an Arraylist doesn't need to exist

Comment: I guess i wasn't notifying the adapter